# How does contextmanager forward a raised exception to the function that it decorates?

Tags: python, contextmanager

How do I write a class that can be used in place of `contextmanager` in this example?

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def f():
    try: 
        yield None
    except Exception as e:
        print(e) # This statement is executed!

with f() as _:
    raise Exception("foo")
```

My attempt:

```
class MyOwnContextManager:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.g.__next__()        

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        pass # What exactly do I put here?

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
        self.g = self.f(*args, **kwds)
        return self

@MyOwnContextManager
def f():
    try: 
        yield None
    except Exception as e:
        print(e) # This statement is NOT executed!

with f() as _:
    raise Exception("foo")
```

`MyOwnContextManager` doesn't let `f` handle the raised `Exception`, unlike the built-in `contextmanager`, which calls `print(e)`. How do I handle the exception that is raised inside of the context with the function that is decorated by `MyOwnContextManager`?

Comment: the f() try...except block is executed during the enter phase. The raised foo does not happen inside f(). Only inside `__exit__` you can handle it. Return True for a fix or False for reraise.

Comment: @Daraan okay, I see... Do you know if it's possible to somehow handle the exception inside of `f`'s try...except? The native `contextmanager` somehow lets you do it, and I can't figure out how it's possible.

Comment: @Daraan **Docs:** [At the point where the generator yields, the block nested in the with statement is executed. The generator is then resumed after the block is exited. **If an unhandled exception occurs in the block, it is reraised inside the generator at the point where the yield occurred**. Thus, you can use a try…except…finally statement to trap the error (if any), or ensure that some cleanup takes place.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html). Is there some way to replicate this by hand or is it a built in language feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic happens with `self.g.throw` where you pass it back to your own block.

```py
class MyOwnContextManager:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.g.__next__()        

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        try:
            self.g.throw(type, value, traceback) # go back to your function
            raise RuntimeError("generator didn't stop after throw()")
        except StopIteration as exc:
            print("stopping itter returning", exc is not value, value)
            return exc is not value

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
        self.g = self.f(*args, **kwds)
        return self

@MyOwnContextManager
def f():
    print("init")
    try: 
        print("yielding")
        yield None
        print("yiedled") # will not happen
    except Exception as e:
        print("handler", e)
```

#### Output

```
init  
yielding  
go  
handler foo
stopping itter returning True <class 'Exception'> foo
```